# Loop to convert decimal comma (,) into dot (.) to change class of data.frame columns

Tags: regex, r

I would like to convert the decimal comma `,` into a dot `.`.
As i'm not using `read.table` to import the data, i can't change it from the source.
I'm actually using a query with `RODBC` package to import. 
And the database (Teradata) just outputs this way decimals.
For this case in particular, i'm somehow forced to modify the data using regex.
The point of this, is obviously to convert the object to numeric.

#### Here is an example

```
df <- data.frame(x1 = c("0,1012312", "0,165749", "0,12412", "0,6248223"), 
                 x2 = c("0,012312","0,5749", "0,112", "0,223"),
                 x1 = c("0,312", "0,65749", "0,2", "0,8223"), 
                 x2 = c("0,2312","0,49", "0,54412", "0,623")
                 , stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df
str(df)

### What i've tried
```

**attempt 1**

```
for(i in 1:4){
  gsub(",", ".", df[ , i])
}

df
```

**attempt 2**

```
inx = 1:4
fc <- function(x, inx){
  nm <- names(x)[inx]
  gsub(pattern = ",", replacement = ".", x = x[nm])
}
sapply(df, fc, c(df, inx))
```

Neither works, however if i change each column individually it works.

```
i <- 1
gsub(",", ".", df[ , i])}
[1] "0.1012312" "0.165749"  "0.12412"   "0.6248223"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Attempt 1**: `gsub` does not modify strings in place - you need to assign it back to `df[,i]`.

```
df[,i] <- gsub(",", ".", df[ , i])
```

**Attempt 2**: Right idea. But `x[nm]` gives you a data frame, while `gsub` takes vectors. Better to do `x[,nm]`, with optional `drop = TRUE` (this is default). Also, you have the arguments of your function moved around. You want to apply `fc` over the different values of `inx`, keeping `x = df` fixed.

Try:

```
inx = 1:4
fc <- function(x, inx){
  nm <- names(x)[inx]
  gsub(pattern = ",", replacement = ".", x = x[,nm])
}
sapply(inx, fc, x = df)
```

This returns a matrix because `sapply` will try to simplify. If this is not desired, use `lapply` and wrap it in a data frame.

```
data.frame(lapply(inx, fc, x = df))
```

Or to do it in one line with an anonymous function. Data frames are fundamentally lists, so you can iterate over the columns with `lapply` like so.

```
data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) gsub(",", ".", x, fixed = TRUE)))
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to assign the result of your loop:

```
for(i in 1:4){
  df[ , i] <- as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", df[ , i]))
}
df
str(df)
```

You can also do the 'looping' with `lapply`:

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", x)))
```

Comment: I didn't realize you can assign a list into a data frame with `df[] <- .`. Cool.

Answer (score 4):

You can proceed like this using the `plyr` package

```
df <- data.frame(x1 = c("0,1012312", "0,165749", "0,12412", "0,6248223"),
                 x2 = c("0,012312","0,5749", "0,112", "0,223"),
                 x3 = c("0,312", "0,65749", "0,2", "0,8223"),
                 x4 = c("0,2312","0,49", "0,54412", "0,623")
                 , stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

str(df)
## 'data.frame':    4 obs. of  4 variables:
##  $ x1: chr  "0,1012312" "0,165749" "0,12412" "0,6248223"
##  $ x2: chr  "0,012312" "0,5749" "0,112" "0,223"
##  $ x3: chr  "0,312" "0,65749" "0,2" "0,8223"
##  $ x4: chr  "0,2312" "0,49" "0,54412" "0,623"


require(plyr)
correct_decim <- function(x)
    as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", x, fixed = TRUE))

new_df <- colwise(correct_decim)(df)
str(new_df)
## 'data.frame':    4 obs. of  4 variables:
##  $ x1: num  0.101 0.166 0.124 0.625
##  $ x2: num  0.0123 0.5749 0.112 0.223
##  $ x3: num  0.312 0.657 0.2 0.822
##  $ x4: num  0.231 0.49 0.544 0.623
```

An if for some reason you want stick with base R, try :

```
data.frame(do.call(cbind, lapply(df, correct_decim)))
##        x1       x2      x3      x4
## 1 0.10123 0.012312 0.31200 0.23120
## 2 0.16575 0.574900 0.65749 0.49000
## 3 0.12412 0.112000 0.20000 0.54412
## 4 0.62482 0.223000 0.82230 0.62300
```